# Inserir tentativa antes de apresentar erro (PHP)

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sistema de cadastro de matrícula de aluno no sistema de uma faculdade.

Parte do código onde apresenta o erro ou não é esse:

```
        while (($matricula = fgets($handle, 1024)) !== false) {
            $cont++;
            erro("Lendo matricula $cont de $qtde_matriculas");
            $matricula = trim($matricula);
            if(!is_numeric(trim(substr($matricula,0,5)))){
                erro("matricula $cont invalido [$matricula]");
            }else{
                $arrayReturn = buscarnafaculdade( $matricula );
                if($arrayReturn['status'] == "ERROR" || $arrayReturn == false){
                    erro(" ERRO servidor faculdade para inserir matricula [$matricula]");
                    $result = print_r($arrayReturn);
                    erro($result);
                }else{
                    erro("matricula [$matricula] inserido no no sistema!");
                }
            }
            $matricula = null;
```

Acontece que, se ocorre erro eu pulo para a próxima. Eu gostaria de mudar isso.

Gostaria que fossem feitas um determinado número de tentativas e caso mantivesse o erro em:

```
if($arrayReturn['status'] == "ERROR" || $arrayReturn == false){
                    erro(" ERRO servidor faculdade para inserir matricula [$matricula]");
```

Aí sim parasse.

É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De uma maneira "braçal" você pode implementar da seguinte forma:

```
$NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS = 5;
$attempts = 0;

while (($matricula = fgets($handle, 1024)) !== false) {
    $cont++;
    erro("Lendo matricula $cont de $qtde_matriculas");
    $matricula = trim($matricula);

    if(!is_numeric(trim(substr($matricula,0,5)))){
        erro("matricula $cont invalido [$matricula]");
    }else{
        do{
            $arrayReturn = buscarnafaculdade( $matricula );
            if($arrayReturn['status'] == "ERROR" || $arrayReturn == false){
                $attempts++;

                if ($attempts <= $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS){
                    continue;
                }

                erro(" ERRO servidor faculdade para inserir matricula [$matricula]");
                $result = print_r($arrayReturn);
                erro($result);
            }else{
                erro("matricula [$matricula] inserido no no sistema!");
                $attempts = $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS;
            }
        }while($attempts < $NUM_OF_ATTEMPTS);       

        $attempts = 0;
    }
}

$matricula = null;
```

Não testei o código para ver se ocorrer algum erro de sintaxe mas a ideia seria isso aí.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou!